# Django Rest API image GET error (django.views.static.serve)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Here is my image api link :
https://krisi-doctor.herokuapp.com/api/image/

when i post image file it successfully upload . **when i try to check 4/5 hours later or do any change to heroku** and try to check image at https://krisi-doctor.herokuapp.com/media/images/ it shows error .

app **model.py**

```
from django.db import models

from krisi_user.models import krisi_user


class problem_image(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    krisi_user = models.ForeignKey(krisi_user,on_delete= models.CASCADE,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import problem_image

from .serializers import problem_image_serializer

class problem_image_view(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = problem_image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = problem_image_serializer
```

app **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path , include

from . import views

from rest_framework import routers

#image_router = routers.DefaultRouter('api/image/v1.0',views.problem_image_view)

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('image',views.problem_image_view)
urlpatterns = [

    path('',include(router.urls)),

]
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
#from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

from .models import problem_image

class problem_image_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = problem_image
        fields = ('full_name','email','image','phone')
```

project **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('krisi_user.urls')),
    #path('',include('krisi_image_problem.urls')),
    path('api/', include('krisi_image_problem.urls')),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and **settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for krisi_doctor project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '6tzi5@ni$y926cl1=wmj#&g*kciqaqc4ab%h^hwoiwnoh0^pqo'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['krisi-doctor.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework', #added rest framework app
    'krisi_user', # added krisi_user app
    'krisi_image_problem' # added krisi_image_problem app
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'krisi_doctor.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'krisi_doctor.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
#Acivating Django  Heroku settings
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

**If any one know what's the problem .. Help me.. help will be appreciated..Thanks :)**

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2cMA.png)

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `DEBUG = True` when your site is publicly available, and you shouldn't use `static()` to serve your static files in production. [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) is a common choice for serving static files when using Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store files on the local disk when you use Heroku. The [dynos have an ephemeral filesystem](https://www.heroku.com/dynos), so when the dyno restarts, any local files are lost.

You can use [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to store your media files somewhere else (Amazon S3 is a common choice).